# A regenerative braking system, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: motors, electrical, current

I am currently working on a system of regen braking using two DC motors one of them is driven by the motor controller and the other one is using the main motor to spin in cases of full load and in cases of braking as well.

I need to figure out a way to measure the current produced by the motor in the regen phase before risking and connecting it to the battery pack (Li-on). So my main question is:

What could be used as a mediator circuit to measure the current from the motor?

P.S.: I used a multi meter in series and the Hall (clamp of the multimeter) to measure it and it failed to report anything, but its apparent that there is current.

Comment: what did you use as a load for the regen braking motor?

Comment: If this is a raw cell pack for which you are designing the charging circuitry you need to design the feedback loop to control the current while keeping the temperature sufficiently low and not overcharging it.  If it already has a charge controller built in, then you only need to concern yourself with keeping the voltage you provide it in spec.  Both will ultimately need protections resembling a switching regulator and diode.